# Why would the specifications for this database use an aggregation instead of attributes on an entity?

Tags: database, database-design, schema, erd

I'm trying to better understand designing a database schema.  After reviewing the solution for a problem that I'm working on, I don't understand why the solution chooses to use an aggregation for the attributes "address" and "phone number" for a given "musician".  Here are the specifications, I'm only interested in bullet point 1:

- Each musician that records at Notown has an SSN, a name, an address, and a phone
  number. Poorly paid musicians often share the same address, and no address has more
  than one phone.
- Each instrument used in songs recorded at Notown has a name (e.g., guitar, synthesizer,
  flute) and a musical key (e.g., C, B-flat, E-flat).
- Each album recorded on the Notown label has a title, a copyright date, a format (e.g.,
  CD or MC), and an album identifier.
- Each song recorded at Notown has a title and an author.
- Each musician may play several instruments, and a given instrument may be played by
  several musicians.
- Each album has a number of songs on it, but no song may appear on more than one
  album.
- Each song is performed by one or more musicians, and a musician may perform a number
  of songs.
- Each album has exactly one musician who acts as its producer. A musician may produce several albums, of course.

Here is a solution that I found:

[image]

The ER Diagram I created looks almost exactly the same, except for the fact that I made "address" and "phone number" attributes of "musician" instead of giving each of them an entity set of their own, creating a relationship, and turning it into an aggregation.  I don't understand why this would be done in this situation.  Can anyone explain??  Thank you!

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs. Use an image only to augment text or give what cannot be given via text. Every diagram should have a legend. (You don't explain the notation--there are many.) Use SO edit functionality to insert images /links. Please put into a question only what is relevant to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to see the image you linked to, but anyway...

### no address has more than one phone

This means we should make the phone number an attribute of the address - unless we want to allow for multiple phones per address in the future.

So it would not be completely wrong to make phones a table. But then, we know little about the future. Would there be multiple musicians sharing the same address and the same phones? (I.e. the phone number would be linked to an address.) Or would there be multiple musicians sharing the same address, but each would have their own phone? (I.e. the phone number would be linked to a musician. To use a phone table and link the phones to musicians, however, would only be necessary if a musician could have multiple phone numbers. Otherwise we'd still not make a phone table, but rather make the phone a musician's attribute.)

### poorly paid musicians often share the same address

This means we make the address a table of its own. Thus there is only one row to change in case the phone number or some other attribute changes. If we made the address number a musician's attribute instead, we'd store the address redundantly and could get inconsistent data (e.g. same address, but different phone numbers).

### A possible data model:

- address (address_id, street, city, phone, ...)
- musician (musician_id, ssn, name, address_id, ...)

This is a 1:n relation. A musician has one address; an address can belong to multiple musicians.

Answer (score 0):

The primary purpose of database normalization is to make it more difficult for anomalous data to get into the database. Reading the first bullet point, we see that each address may have zero or one phone numbers associated with it. In other words, the phone number is an attribute of/identified by the address. Which normalization level does this violate?

To illustrate how not normalizing the address fields (including phone number) increases the chances of anomalous data, let's say you have four students staying at that address. This means you have four rows where the address data exists. Suppose the phone number changes. You have to make sure you change all four versions of the data. I said there were four students, but suppose there are actually five and I just missed one? Or suppose you found only three when you went to make the change? An address may have at most one phone number however now you have several copies of the same address but with different phone numbers. This is anomalous data.

If this data is normalized, you would have only one copy to change. Since this data is referenced by all the students who live there, no matter how many, this change is "propagated" to all of them. The integrity of the data is maintained.